# JQGrid mapping issue: Populating JQGrid with data from two related tables

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm currently working with two tables that I'm accessing through NHibernate entity framework:
- Invoices
- InvoiceItems

I need to create an Invoice Items report and include the Invoice table infomration on it as well.

The two tables are connected by InvoiceId. To populate my report data I created a model for the JQGrid that's connected to the "InvoiceItems" data model ( that's where I get the data from ).

My problem is that I can't seem to figuire out how to populate the "InvoiceItems" report with the "Invoice" table field values. Errors such as [Property 'InvoiceDate' not found on Namespace.InvoiceItems] or just [NaN NaN] keep showing up in columns where the information from the parent [Invoices] table should be. I tried using 'InvoiceItems.Invoices.InvoiceDate' syntax for example to map the grid colNames to data names but it doesn't work.

So how can I map the "Invoices" table fields to the grid model that returns fields from both "Invoices" and "InviceItems" data models ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you define colModel property?
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options

Comment: Yes here is a sample. Invoiceitems values are being displayed correctly but not the values from Invoices table.

colmodel of an Invoice field:
    <pre>{ name: 'InvoiceNum', index: 'InvoiceNum', width: 80 }</pre>

colmodel of an Invoiceitems field:
    { name: 'item', index: 'item', width: 80 },

Comment: what is the full colModel property? Please note that you need to add each column to the colModel property. For example, it may be like: colModel: [{ name: 'InvoiceNum', index: 'InvoiceNum', width: 80 }, { name: 'InvoiceDate', index: 'InvoiceDate', width: 80 }] and so on.

Comment: I know and I have already done that. The problem is InvoiceDate (in your example) is part of the InvoiceItems table and InvoiceNum is member of table Invoice. The JqGridresult I'm returning from the Controller is of Type InvoiceItems which has a reference to Invoice table.

Comment: One of the properties in my InvoiceItems data model is of type "Invoice" so while assigning values I can do "InvoiceItems.Invoice.InvoiceNum = 123". But in the JqGrid colmodel I dont get a value when I do the following:
{ name: 'InvoiceItems.Invoice.InvoiceNum', index: 'InvoiceNum', width: 80 }

Comment: what is datatype and url property? if you assign datatype: "xml" and url: "file.aspx", you can load the query.

Comment: datatype: 'json',
url:"/Project/MyControllers/CrPaidInvoiceGrid",

Comment: CrPaidInvoiceGrid.ascx is the control I'm displaying the jQgrid on